# Thoughts on Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Declare a variable called elementAtIndexFive using the let keyword. The value of this variable should be the element with index 5 in the numArray array. Is this correct?

```
const numArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

// TODO: declare the variable elementAtIndexFive and assign it 
//the value of the element with index number 5 in the array numArray

let elementAtIndexFive = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

// This will print the value of variable elementAtIndexFive to the console

console.log('The array element with index 5 is: ', elementAtIndexFive);
```

Answer (score 1):

> [JavaScript arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#accessing_array_elements) are zero-indexed. The first element of an array is at index 0, and the last element is at the index value equal to the value of the array's length property minus 1.

So you can access an array element by index using square bracket notation and it will return the value that is stored at that index.
eg `numArray[5]`

```js
const numArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

// TODO: declare the variable elementAtIndexFive and assign it 
//the value of the element with index number 5 in the array numArray

let elementAtIndexFive = numArray[5];

// This will print the value of variable elementAtIndexFive to the console

console.log('The array element with index 5 is: ', elementAtIndexFive);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`let elementAtIndexFive = numArray[5];`

```js
const numArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

let elementAtIndexFive = numArray[5];

console.log('The array element with index 5 is: ', elementAtIndexFive);
```

You need from the numArray the fifth element and assign it to elementAtIndexFive

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow, here are some suggestions to improve the post : you can add code samples to highlight the code and make it more readable.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it will print as expected as the let keyword only describes a variable only at block storage; your output stream and variable declaration reside in the same scope. Remember you can't redeclare it again.